# (sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ) error when trying to insert values into sqlite3 db

Tags: python, sqlite

basic question that i haven't been able to find the exact solution for.
i'm trying to insert a paramaters into customer table :

```
def cur():
    db = sqlite3.connect("bookdb.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    return cursor

def add_customer(id, name, city, age):
    cursor = cur()
    sql = f'insert into customer(id,name,city,age) VALUES({id}, {name}, {city}, {age})'
    cursor.execute(sql)
    cursor.connection.commit()
```

and when using :

```
add_customer(7, 'jimbo', 'NY', 22)
```

i get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: jimbo
```

it appears to work fine when i only insert integers into the function but not strings, the name column exists and i'm unable to add any strings into it.

Comment: Use placeholders and parameters instead of substituting into the string. This will solve the error (you're missing quotes around `{name}` and `{city}`) and also prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Use `print(sql)` and the problem should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Jut in case it wasn't obvious, here's the correct way to do queries using placeholders, allowing the database connector to do the quoting:

```
db = sqlite3.connect("bookdb.sqlite")
def cur():
    return db.cursor()

def add_customer(id, name, city, age):
    cursor = cur()
    sql = 'insert into customer(id,name,city,age) VALUES(?, ?, ?);'
    cursor.execute(sql, (name, city, age))
    cursor.connection.commit()
```

You don't really want `db` to be a function local variable.  You should have it be a global, so you can create more cursors from it later on.